# Configure different versions of PHP with NGINX to work on subfolders

Tags: php, webserver, nginx

I have a NGINX configuration set up like below so that accessing
`stg.server.org` will be served by `PHP 5.6 (php56-php-fpm running on port 9000)`
 and
`stg.server.org/simon/apps/` will be served by `PHP 7.3 (php-fpm running on port 9001)` but without success. Does anyone have a clue on how to achieve this?

```
server {
    listen stg.server.org:80;
    server_name stg.server.org;

    root   /var/www/html/;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    #charset koi8-r;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access_log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/error_log   error;

   location / {
          root   /var/www/html/;
          index index.php index.html index.htm;
          try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

   # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    location ~ \.php$ {

            root    /var/www/html/;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;  #php-fpm PHP 5.6
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include         fastcgi_params;
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;

    }

    location /simon/apps/ {

      root /var/www/stg.server.org/simon/apps/;
      index index.php index.html index.htm;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;

      location ~ \.php$ {

            root /var/www/apps-stg.unep.org/simon/pims/;
            try_files $uri =404
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9001;  #php-fpm PHP 7.3
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include  fastcgi_params;

      }


  }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems with your configuration.

The *regular expression* `location` takes precedence over a *prefix* `location` unless the `^~` modifier is used. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

The path to the file is constructed by concatenating the value of `root` with the URI, so the part of the path `/simon/apps/`, which appears in the URI should not also appear in the `root` value.

The `try_files` statement in the `location ^~ /simon/apps/` block should presumably default to the `/simon/apps/index.php` script and not the `/index.php`.

`root` and `index` directives are inherited, and do not need to be repeated within blocks where the value has not changed.

For example:

```
root /var/www/html;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

location / { ... }
location ~ \.php$ { ... }

location ^~ /simon/apps/ {
    root /var/www/stg.server.org;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /simon/apps/index.php?$query_string;

    location ~ \.php$ { ... }
}
```

In your question, you have a different path for the PHP scripts. It is simpler to keep the PHP files within the same document root. The above will only work if the URI `/simon/apps/index.php` is located at the path `/var/www/stg.server.org/simon/apps/index.php`.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my configuration file, `stg.server.org` works fine, but `stg.server.org/simon/apps/` is not processed by PHP-FPM. Instead, the browser downloads index.php file.

Comment: I notice a missing `;` after the `try_files` statement in your nested `location` block.

Comment: It works when I access using  `http://stg.server.org/simon/apps/index.php` but when I try `http://stg.server.org/simon/apps/` (without index.php), it downloads the file index.php

Comment: Have you cleared the browser's cache?

Comment: Lol, wanted to say the problem was the browser's cache but you beat me to it :-)